# Nuxtjs data() variable cannot change

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I hava a simple nuxt/vue app. It uses an API to call filters and data, but the fetch hook dont change the variable. Here's my code:

```
data() {
    return {
      filters: {},
      fulldata: [],
      filterName: '',
    }
  },

  async fetch({app}) {
    app.$axios.$get('/api/oklevelek').then(data => {
      this.fulldata = data
      this.filters = data.possibleFilters
      console.log(this.fulldata) //data shows
    })
    console.log('adatok')
    console.log(this.fulldata) //undefined
  },

  fetchOnServer: true,
  methods: {
    test() { //test method for data
      console.log('test')
      console.log(this.fulldata) //undefined
    },
  },
```

Thanks for your time and appreciate your help!

Comment: I tried to solve your problem. I don't understand why it does not works... It really should.
I created this sand box for my tests :
https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxtjs-fetch-does-not-work-dgmd9
I also tried to use the store but I was not able to ... (https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/). As fetch has been deprecated, I would suggest you to use asyncData or to fetch the data on mounted() event and not fetch() event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **await** the response from your fetch call. At the moment, you’re trying to console.log `this.fulldata` immediately after calling the api, before the data has had chance to return.

```
async fetch({app}) {
  app.$axios.$get('/api/oklevelek').then(data => {
    this.fulldata = data
    this.filters = data.possibleFilters
    console.log(this.fulldata) //data shows
  })
  console.log('adatok')
  // this runs immediately after the api call
  console.log(this.fulldata) //undefined
}
```

This should help:

```
async fetch({app}) {
  // add await here
  let { data } = await app.$axios.$get('/api/oklevelek')
  // now this code waits for the api call to finish
  this.fulldata = data
  this.filters = data.possibleFilters
  console.log(this.fulldata)
  console.log('adatok')
  console.log(this.fulldata)
}
```